# ¿Cómo mostrar contador hasta que sea igual a un valor?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, bucles, shell-script

Necesito, mediante un bucle until, rellenar los números entre 2 valores pasados por parámetros, por ejemplo:

```
./ejercicio 10 15
10 11 12 13 14 15
./ejercicio 15 10
15 14 13 12 11 10
```

Mi código actual es este:

```
#!/bin/bash

if `test $# -ne 2`                  
then                            
    echo "Numero de parametros incorrecto"      
    echo "Uso del programa: $0 numero1 numero2"  p
    exit 1;                     
fi

contador=$1
until test $contador -eq $2 
do
    if `test $1 -ge $2`
    then
        echo $contador
        contador=`expr $contador - 1`
    else
        echo $contador
        contador=`expr $contador + 1`
    fi
done
```

El problema que tengo es que no me muestra el último numero, es decir si el segundo parámetro es 20 me muestra solo hasta el 19 (tanto en caso creciente como decreciente).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que ocurre es que el ciclo no continúa ni bien se establece la condición de igualdad, por lo que jamás llegas a mostrar el limite al que llegó, **la solución simple es agregar un `echo $contador` justo a la salida del ciclo**. Por otro lado, un `do .. while` tampoco resuelve el problema, si el `echo` esta antes del incremento, no se va a mostrar el último de los valores, si el `echo`está después del incremento, no verías el primero de los valores.

La solución, entiendo, pasa por "romper" el ciclo desde adentro, una vez encontrada la condición de salida:

```
contador=$1
while true ; do

    echo $contador
    if [ "$contador" -eq "$2" ];then
        break
    fi

    if [ $1 -ge $2 ]
        then
            contador=`expr $contador - 1`
        else
            contador=`expr $contador + 1`
    fi

done
```

Detalle:

- Estamos frente a un `while` infinito: `while true ; do` que "rompemos" desde adentro
- la condición de salida es lo primero que hacemos luego de mostrar el valor de `contador` cuando detectamos que `contador` es igual al 2do límite, salimos del loop con un `break`.
- El código de incremento o decremento es el mismo, solo reemplace el uso de `test` por el built-in de bash `[`

Answer (score 2):

Cuando dices que quieres un script `ejercicio` que haga lo siguiente:

```
./ejercicio 10 15
10 11 12 13 14 15
./ejercicio 15 10
15 14 13 12 11 10
```

De hecho estás definiendo el comando `seq` (por *seq*uential, de *secuencial*):

```
$ seq 10 15
10
11
12
13
14
15
$ seq 15 10
15
14
13
12
11
10
```

Si quieres que todos los números aparezcan en la misma línea, utiliza el parámetro `-s` que define el delimitador:

```
$ seq -s ' ' 10 15
10 11 12 13 14 15
```

Answer (score 1):

No hace falta el `expr`, sería mas simple hacerlos así:

```
operador="+"
if [[ $2 < $1 ]]; then
  operador="-"
fi

valor1=$1
until [[ $valor1 == $2 ]]; do
  valor1=$((valor1 $operador 1))
  echo "$valor1"
done
```

O, si necesitas asegurarte que los inputs son sanos (es decir solo 2, numéricos y no vacíos), haz:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 2 ]
then                            
    echo "Numero de parametros incorrecto"      
    echo "Uso del programa: $0 numero1 numero2"  p
    exit 1;                     
fi

if [[ ! "$1$2" =~ ^[-+0-9]*$ ]]; then
  echo "El programa solo acepta valores numericos"
  exit 1
fi

if [[ -z $1 || -z $2 ]]; then
  echo "El programa no accepta paremetros vacios"
  exit 1;
fi

operador="+"
if [[ $2 < $1 ]]; then
  operador="-"
fi

valor1=$1
until [[ $valor1 == $2 ]]; do
  valor1=$((valor1 $operador 1))
  echo "$valor1"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo optaría por no claudicar en el uso del `until` y para poder seguirlo utilizando, se me ocurre preprocesar la variable de término.

Como mencionaba @patricio-moracho, en el caso del ciclo `until`, nunca va a llegar al final puesto que así se maneja `until`. Cuando esa condición es cierta entonces cesa el ciclo. Todo lo contrario al ciclo `while`.

Entonces, si el punto del `until` es que "el final llega demasiado pronto", pues simplemente extendemos ese tan famoso final.

Es decir, si queremos que el `until` vaya de `i` a `n`, pero en `n` sale del ciclo, entonces va de `i` a `n-1`, entonces simplemente redefinimos la variable que marca el final con una distancia de "1", ya sea "+1" o "-1", según sea en incremento o decremento, para asegurarnos de que el final, al ser `k=n+-1`, permitirá a`until` imprimir el caso `k-1` o `k+1`, que en ambos casos será "n".

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# -ne 2 ]]
then                            
    echo "Numero de parametros incorrecto"      
    echo "Uso del programa: $0 numero1 numero2"
    exit 1     
fi

[[ $1 -lt $2 ]] && fin=$(($2+1)) || fin=$(($2-1))

contador=$1
until [[ $contador -eq $fin ]]
do
    [[ $1 -ge $2 ]] \
        && echo $((contador--)) \
        || echo $((contador++))
done
```

Otra manera que se me ocurre, semejante a la anterior, es extender la variable final en el mismo ciclo, para eso utilizo una variable `lock` que va a permitir que la variable final sólo aumente o disminuya en 1 sólo una vez.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# -ne 2 ]]
then                            
    echo "Numero de parametros incorrecto"      
    echo "Uso del programa: $0 numero1 numero2"
    exit 1     
fi

fin=$2
lock=1

contador=$1
until [[ $contador -eq $fin ]]
do
    if [[ $1 -ge $2 ]]
    then
        [[ $lock -eq 0 ]] || ((--fin)) && lock=0
        echo $((contador--))
    else
        [[ $lock -eq 0 ]] || ((++fin)) && lock=0
        echo $((contador++))
    fi
done
```

Sólo que en esta última, si desde el inicio tanto `$1` como `$2` son iguales, entonces se cumple la condición del `until` desde el comienzo y por lo tanto ni siquiera entraría al ciclo.